# Cannot set defaultValue in React-Select component

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to set defaultValue to React-Select component. I'm going with documentation but cannot help myself with that.
I have assigned below Select component:

```
<Select
        styles={selectStyles}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        isMulti
        placeholder={t('filter.clinicsSelect')}
        options={paidVisitsOptions}
        defaultValue={transformedDefaultOptions}
        onChange={(event) => clinicsFilterHandler(event)}
        theme={(theme) => ({
          ...theme,
          colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            primary: colors.primary,
          },
        })}
      />
```

variable assigned to defaultValue looks like this:

```
const transformedDefaultOptions = defaultOptions.map((option) => ({
    value: option,
    label: option,
  }));
```

this is what I see when I console.log(transformedDefaultOptions)
[image]

Can You please let me know what I do wrong here ?

Comment: Are you certain that the `defaultOptions` items match the ones in `paidVisitsOptions` ?

Comment: and are the `defaultOptions` available on the first render ? or do you fetch them from somewhere, and the become available after the fetch ? Because the `defaultValue` is only applicable on the initial render of the `Select`.

Comment: good inputs. let me look at it this way